# Can Enum.ToString support precision specifiers like "X2"?

Tags: c#, enums, tostring

`Enum.ToString(string)` does not support direct usage of precision specifiers like `X2` or `D5` to apply a padding to numeric values.  [Formattings like `ToString("X")` or `ToString("D")` are implemented and well documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw(v=vs.110).aspx). Of course I can explicitely cast it to `int` before and so make use of the format specifiers implemented for ints to convert it to a padded string.

I was wondering if there is some direct support for this functionallity for enum without the need to cast them. On first sight it seems strange that this is not directly implemented as it was done for ints or other numeric types. But maybe I am missing something more important which could explicitely explain that it wasn't done like that for enums?

```
public enum Number
{
    Ten = 10
}

Console.WriteLine(Number.Ten);                      //OK: Ten
Console.WriteLine(Number.Ten.ToString());           //OK: Ten
Console.WriteLine(Number.Ten.ToString("D"));        //OK: 10
Console.WriteLine(Number.Ten.ToString("D5"));       //Expected 00010 - Failed: System.FormatException, can only be "G","g","X","x","F","f","D" or 
Console.WriteLine(Number.Ten.ToString("X"));        //OK: 0000000A
Console.WriteLine(Number.Ten.ToString("X2"));       //Expected 0A - Failed: System.FormatException, can only be "G","g","X","x","F","f","D" or "d"
Console.WriteLine(10.ToString("X2"));               //OK: 0A
Console.WriteLine(10.ToString("D5"));               //OK: 00010
Console.WriteLine(((int)Number.Ten).ToString("X2"));//OK: 0A
```

A short summary from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43101989/2455604):
It is not explicitely there because it is already implicitely done depending on the size of the underlying type. So if you like `X2` instead of `X8` just use byte as underlying type and `ToString("X")` will behave like `ToString("X2")`.

Comment: That's life. Consider writing an extension method if you need this for a specific enum.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you expect. Only the language designers can tell you why. Probably because it's a kinda odd thing to want or need to do. The solution is just to cast it: `((int)Number.Ten).ToString("D5")`

Comment: @apk yeah - but c# is actually supporting it for ints - enums are usually ints - so why would the language designer not implement this relatively obvious feature?

Comment: You would have to ask the language designers that.  This really isn't the place for 'Why was the decision made to support such and such a feature in the language'.

Comment: Personally, I'm surprised they support any formatting. This seems like a very edge case.

Comment: @MattBurland why would it be more odd to do than with a simple integer?

Comment: Contrary to that -1, I think this is a great question and I wish I had the answer. Hope my +1 helps.

Comment: @Marwie: Because *it's not an integer*, it's an enum. That's not what enums are for.

Comment: @flaZer answer to your particular wish - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/ (somewhat generic, but applies to 99% of such questions - which are officially on-topic, just not answerable)

Comment: @MattBurland But... [they are kind of related to integers...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) - quote: "The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong." The default being int - As such the underlying type is in any case numeric. That makes it quite obvious to support the conversions, right?

Comment: @Marwie: That they are backed by integers (or bytes, or longs, or whatever) is neither here nor there. It wouldn't (usually) really make sense to do math with them either despite being integers behind the scenes. For example `Color.Red + Color.Blue` doesn't make sense (the answer better be `Color.Purple`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe because enum can be an byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

If you check .net source code you'll see the implementation of ToString("X"):

```
switch (Convert.GetTypeCode(value))
  {
    case TypeCode.Boolean:
      return Convert.ToByte((bool) value).ToString("X2", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.Char:
      return ((ushort) (char) value).ToString("X4", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.SByte:
      return ((byte) (sbyte) value).ToString("X2", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.Byte:
      return ((byte) value).ToString("X2", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.Int16:
      return ((ushort) (short) value).ToString("X4", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.UInt16:
      return ((ushort) value).ToString("X4", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.Int32:
      return ((uint) (int) value).ToString("X8", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.UInt32:
      return ((uint) value).ToString("X8", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.Int64:
      return ((ulong) (long) value).ToString("X16", (IFormatProvider) null);
    case TypeCode.UInt64:
      return ((ulong) value).ToString("X16", (IFormatProvider) null);
    default:
      throw new InvalidOperationException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidOperation_UnknownEnumType"));
  }
```

If you change your code to this, it'll use ToString("X2"):

```
public enum Number : byte
{
    Ten = 10
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting code extract from .NET. So in fact the underlying type actually implies already a formatting with X2/X4 etc...

Comment: I'm accepting this as answer because it seems that the question will soon be closed and this answer is leading into the right direction: namely that the underlying type implies already a formatting precision when using `ToString("X")`.

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of [`Enum.ToString()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,e02a1db31e011144) shows that it was designed so that only certain format specifiers can be used:

```
    public String ToString(String format) {
        if (format == null || format.Length == 0)
            format = "G";

        if (String.Compare(format, "G", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            return ToString();

        if (String.Compare(format, "D", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            return GetValue().ToString();

        if (String.Compare(format, "X", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            return InternalFormattedHexString(GetValue());

        if (String.Compare(format, "F", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            return InternalFlagsFormat((RuntimeType)GetType(), GetValue());

        throw new FormatException(Environment.GetResourceString("Format_InvalidEnumFormatSpecification"));
    }
```

I think it covers the most common scenarios: being able to show its numeric, hexadecimal, or string representation. The workaround of an explicit cast seems cheap enough to not need to bake it into the framework.

If you want to use the underlying type's `ToString()` without knowing what the specific type is (without having to cast!), you could maybe do something like:

```
var formattedValue = string.Format("{0:X2}", 
    Convert.ChangeType(Number.Ten, Number.Ten.GetTypeCode()));
```

Which would ouput "0A". This could be wrapped up easily in an extension method.

Comment: And clearly documented that way [MSDN:Enumeration Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e(v=vs.110).aspx)